# Connection string failing for SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, iis, sql-server-2012, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to my db on my local machine  with the following connection string and it fails for the following connection string

```
conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);DataBase=dnn6;Integrated Security=SSPI");
```

I'm using IIS 6 as my web server and when I open that page I get the following error.

> Cannot open database "dnn6" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\demo'.

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the IIS account being used to access SQL Server (`IIS APPPOOL\demo`) does not have access to it.

You need to either:

- grant permission for the user `IIS APPPOOL\demo` to your SQL Server
- use impersonation to connect to SQL Server with a user account that has access
- use SQL Server Logins to access SQL Server using a named user (not recommended these days)

Comment: How do i do the first option?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, create a new Login in SQL Server for the `IIS APPPOOL\demo` user, then add a database user for the login and grant it the appropriate permissions.

Comment: It's no different from adding access for any other user to SQL Server.